# View restrictions about distinct?

Tags: oracle, view, distinct

I found information that we cannot delete rows from view which in query have distinct but I want to show example :

```
create table tb001 ( id number );
insert into tb001 values (1); 
insert into tb001 values (2);

create table tb002 ( id number );
insert into tb002 values (1); 
insert into tb002 values (2);
insert into tb002 values (2);

create view vw_tb001 as select distinct(id) from tb001;
create view vw_tb002 as select distinct(id) from tb002;
```

So in the first version we can delete from view `vw_tb001`, because we havn't duplicate rows
In the second version we cannot delete from view `vw_tb002`.
So I am confused in rule about restrictions ? Need experts help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any view created by running the distinct operation on a table should stop you from deleting from the view.  Using the example above I would disagree that you could delete from vw_tb001 even though there are no duplicates in tb001.

Comment: But I checked in toad or sqlplus, it is true( oracle 12c ), I deleted rows from tb001, I share this because I saw in exam question about it and these answer very confused.

Comment: There will be a difference between deleting from tb001 and vw_tb001.  You should be able to change the underlying table that the views are built on in both cases.  As @Littlefoot shows in their answer, you can also build a trigger to do this for you, simulating deleting from the view, but actually in the background just deleting from the table again.

Comment: Sorry I forget write vw_tb001, cannot edited, I am about it.

Comment: So @Wano_Anth I checked in toad again and you are right, I Think it is my bad :)) oh sorry. Probably I wrote table name not view name in command, can be this.

Comment: Can you help me in some questions ? I am preparing to exam and need some decision ( second time )

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can still delete rows from such a view. Here's how.

Test case first:

```
SQL> drop table tb002;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table tb002 ( id number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tb002 values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tb002 values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tb002 values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> create view vw_tb002 as select distinct(id) from tb002;

View created.

SQL>
```

Keyword: **instead of** trigger; I'll create one that "replaces" delete functionality. The same can be done for inserts or updates as well. Basically, it tells Oracle what to do when you're deleting from the view, so - "instead of" deleting row(s) from the view, it'll delete rows from its underlying table:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_iof_vw
  2    instead of delete on vw_tb002
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    delete from tb002 where id = :old.id;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

---

Let's see how it works:

Contents at the beginning:

```
SQL> select * from tb002;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         2

SQL> select * from vw_tb002;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
```

Deleting:

```
SQL> delete from vw_tb002 where id = 2;

1 row deleted.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From tb002;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> select * from vw_tb002;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for more information which you share with me and sorry for my english bad, but I am about that restriction not work in some cases, I checked it in toad or sqlplus, for first version delete is working. So iti confused when you see in exam about these answer and cannot give decision what to choose.I will remember your idea about trigger it is new for me.

Comment: Can you help me in some questions ? I am preparing to exam and need some decision )))